# R package Error caused by difference between GSL library on 32 bit and 64 bit windows?

Tags: c++, r, windows

I am working on an R package using GNU GSL library. The GSL library is downloaded from http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html.  Compiling for both x64 and i386 passed R CMD check. The source package can also be installed on 32bit and 64 bit windows. Everything works ok on 64 bit windows.

However, the package crashes on 32 bit windows and throwing the following error message
"gsl:: \blas\blas.c:107 Error Length Default GSL Error handler invoked"

I checked the original source code

```
gsl_vector_view ci = gsl_matrix_row (A, i);
gsl_vector_view ck = gsl_matrix_row (A, k);
Rprintf("cisize=%d\n,cksize=%d\n",ci.vector.size,ck.vector.size);

gsl_vector_view di = gsl_vector_subvector(&ci.vector, 0, i);
gsl_vector_view dk = gsl_vector_subvector(&ck.vector, 0, i);
Rprintf("disize=%d\n,dksize=%d\n",di.vector.size,dk.vector.size);
gsl_blas_ddot (&di.vector, &dk.vector, &sum);
```

The error is caused by the last line of code  gsl_blas_ddot due to di.vector.size and dk.vector.size.

On windows 64, the output print is:

```
cisize=5
cksize=5
disize=1
dksize=1
```

And on windows 32, the output print is not fixed, one output is:

```
cisize=337939976
cksize=1
disize=0
dksize=326253992
```

another ouput is

```
cisize=251898432
cksize=1
disize=0
dksize=151229056
```

Could any one can tell where is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The same problem occurs using  GSL  from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error was caused by the "gsl_matrix_row" function, I rewrote the code to implement the function myself:

```
gsl_vector *di=gsl_vector_alloc(i);
gsl_vector *dk=gsl_vector_alloc(i);
for(l = 0; l < i; l++)
 {
     gsl_vector_set(di,l,gsl_vector_get(ci,l));
     gsl_vector_set(dk,l,gsl_vector_get(ck,l));
 }

gsl_vector_free(di);
gsl_vector_free(dk);
```

However, I still do not know why "gsl_matrix_row" did not work under 32bit windows machines.